# How to assign an instance to a variable - .find() / .where() - and access it's values - RUBY on RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, instance

account = Account.find(params[:account_id])

account_to_receive = Account.where(number_account: transaction.account_to_transfer)

So I am building a bank app
I would like to transfer an amount to another bank account
but accessing it through it's number_account

Assigning with where()
what I get #Account::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x4290
So can not access it's values

Differently from using .find()
So I get #<Account:0x00007f39a45e5760
And I could then access everything

Anyone to bright me on how to do that?

Comment: Didn’t understand your question clearly. But looks like you want to access a single record from the collection. Calling where returns a ActiveRecord_Relation object to get the single record you can call the following
account_to_receive = Account.where(number_account: transaction.account_to_transfer).first
or you can call  Account.find_by(number_account: transaction.account_to_transfer). Then you can access the attributes from the assigned variable.

Comment: Hei Farhad! Thank you for your tip. You got my question. I actually already solved it using .find_by(). Thank you! <3

Answer (score 0):

```rb
account = Account.find(params[:account_id])

account_to_receive = Account.find_by(number_account: transaction.account_to_transfer)

# Credit `account_to_receive` from the amount from `account`
```

But pay attention, this means you already know the 2 accounts. If you're using IBAN, it seems difficult to have all accounts stored in your database.